# HTML and CSS: creating an online game's board - Layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a basic web-based game using Vanilla JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. I have coded a grid using flex and a basic table. The code is long and ugly. Is there a simpler way to do this? or a more efficient way?

```
[JS Fiddle Example][1]
```

[1]:
This is the JS fiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/CosmoCamus/4qgts08x/1/

Comment: *"The code is long and ugly"* ... code is usually always long and eventually ugly. Does your code even work would be a better question?

Comment: haha yeah fair point. It works, just not sure if it's a good approach or not

Comment: "It works," if it works then it works. Good approach is for version 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily by using flex. And customize it according to your use:

```css
.grider {

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    border: 1px outset #999;
}

.grider > div {
    border: 1px inset #999;
    margin: 1px;
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grider">

    <div>top-left</div>
    <div>top-middle</div>
    <div>top-right</div>
    <div>middle-left</div>
    <div>center</div>
    <div>middle-right</div>
    <div>bottom-left</div>
    <div>bottom-middle</div>
    <div>bottom-right</div>

</div>
```

Comment: smarter would be to create the whole grid through JS. Easier then to hardcode a grid with hundrets of cells when JS can do it on its own.